# boost asio post request with large body

Tags: c++, http, post, boost, asio

I am trying to use boost::asio to make a synchronous http POST request to localhost:55001/predict with a large body (around 8784000 characters). I am able to do this just fine in python using the `requests` package. My server is able to handle the large body just fine so I know the issue is probably not on the server side.

The Problem:
I set up my request based on other stackoverflow posts for boost::asio POST requests. Here is the main chunk of code for how I set up my POST request. EDIT: I need to use Boost because my client cannot use C++11.

The `features` variable contains a very long string (360 JSONs represented as string delimited by &).

```
boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);
request_stream << "POST " << /predict << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << localhost:55001 << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Length: " << features.length() << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
request_stream << features;

// Send the request
boost::asio::write(socket, request);

// Get the response
boost::asio::streambuf response;
boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");
```

I get the following error/response from the server:

> Response returned with status code 413
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl >: (1): expected value

The Jetty server I'm sending the request to complains of a `HttpParser:HttpParser Full` which implies that the request is to large. Considering I was able to send the full request using Python's request package I know the the Jetty server is definitely able to handle requests of this size. However, this means I am packaging my request incorrectly with boost::asio.

When `features` just contained 2 JSONs (still delimited by `&`) everything works fine and the response contains the results I expect.

I suspect that this issue is because I am writing too much data to the buffer and that I need to send several buffers in a single request. Furthermore, I imagine that Python's request package is handling these issues internally which is why the python code works just fine. Here is the line I use to send the request in python.

```
response = requests.post('http://localhost:55001/predict', data=features.encode('utf-8'))
```

1) Can someone explain how to send a lot of data in the request body of a synchronous POST request using boost::asio? I am unfamiliar with C++ so an example would be helpful.

2) Is Python's Request package abstracting these issues away from me?

Let me know if there is additional information I can provide to help you answer this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `request_stream << "POST " << /predict << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";` you need to change this to something like `request_stream << "POST /predict/ HTTP/1.1 \r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

Boost is great but if all you're trying to do is HTTP GET and POST methods (and you are using C++11) then consider something like [cpr C++ Requests](https://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/). It's a lightweight library that wraps libcurl and is modeled after the Python Requests project.

From [the documentation](https://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/introduction.html), here is a quick example of making a POST request

```
#include <cpr/cpr.h>

auto r = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{"http://www.httpbin.org/post"},
                   cpr::Body{"This is raw POST data"},
                   cpr::Header{{"Content-Type", "text/plain"}});
std::cout << r.text << std::endl;

/*
 * {
 *   "args": {},
 *   "data": "This is raw POST data",
 *   "files": {},
 *   "form": {},
 *   "headers": {
 *     ..
 *     "Content-Type": "text/plain",
 *     ..
 *   },
 *   "json": null,
 *   "url": "http://www.httpbin.org/post"
 * }
 */
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. One caveat that I will add to the original post, is that I cannot use C++11. My client still hasn't updated to that which is why I am trying to use Boost. If there is a way to do cpr without relying on C++11 then that would be perfect.

Comment: If you can't use C++11 then you should try either native libcurl API or there is a C++ wrapper for it called [curlpp](http://www.curlpp.org/).  libcurl will do everything you want but you'll have to do more of the heavy lifting yourself.

Comment: ok thanks - i'll try that. Do you know if libcurl is a header only library? it looks like i just need to include <curl/curl.h>

Comment: @Aakash282 No you’ll have to link to it.